# Insertion Of dynamic dropdownlist values(of each row) from a gridview to tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

//code in aspx.

```
   </asp:TemplateField>
        :
        :
        :
   <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="didDdl" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="departmentsDataSource" 
    DataTextField="Department" 
    DataValueField="DepartmentID" 
    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("DepartmentID") %>' 
    Enabled="False" />
   </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

Q:I have to insert the selected dropdownlist items to a table all at a once i.e when i click a **submit** button(which i have not shown here) then all the selected values should go at a time to a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is you are using Gridview. So this will work.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> lst = new List<string>();

    foreach(GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (gvr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            lst.Add(((DropDownList)gvr.FindControl("didDdl")).SelectedValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Improvised solution

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("INSET INTO [Table] ");

    string template = " SELECT @{0} UNION ALL ";


    foreach(GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (gvr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string value = ((DropDownList)gvr.FindControl("didDdl")).SelectedValue;

            sb.AppendFormat(template, value);
            comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + value, value));

        }
    }
    comm.CommandText = sb.ToString()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read values from your template columns then build an once Insert statement to SQL server.

the following example shows how to insert Multiple Records using One Insert Statement:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstCol, SecondCol)
SELECT 'First' ,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Second' ,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Third' ,3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fourth' ,4
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fifth' ,5
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way i can think of is get the values inside an arrayList and through for loop insert the values into SQL.